# How do I get an OLEObject by progID?

Tags: excel, vba

I can get `progID` of an OLEObject by `OLEObject.progID` property.

reference as https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.progid

How could I get the `OLEObject` by `progID`?

Comment: Could you post some relevant code showing how you mean to utilize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OLEObject by ProgId

- Loop through the collection and exit the loop when found. Use a `boolean` to determine if it was found.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testOLE()
    
    Dim ole As OLEObject
    Dim wasFound As Boolean
    
    For Each ole In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        If ole.progID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
            wasFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ole
    
    If wasFound Then
        ' Continue to work with found object, e.g.:
        MsgBox "Found '" & ole.Name & ".", vbInformation, "Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not find.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```